# Can you convert my address (bytes20) type to a bytes32 string?

Tags: solidity, web3js, addresses, accounts, bytes32

I am running into an error for:

```
TypeError: Type address payable is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32.
```

Due to the fact that I am using my address `0x0D81d9E21BD7C5bB095535624DcB0759E64B3899`

I tried `web3.utils.padLeft(web3.utils.hexToBytes(yourAddressString, 32);` from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58101282/how-to-convert-address-type-to-bytes32-via-web3 but had no avail. If somebody can convert my address `0x0D81d9E21BD7C5bB095535624DcB0759E64B3899` to bytes32 and tell me how they did it, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: But why would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, answer is use padding

example -> `0x0000000000000000000000000D81d9E21BD7C5bB095535624DcB0759E64B3899`

Sometimes the simplest answers are right infront of you

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Solidity answer to it:

```
function addressToBytes32(address _addr) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
    return bytes32(uint256(uint160(_addr)));
}
```

Source: https://github.com/LayerZero-Labs/LayerZero-v2/blob/bf4318b/oapp/contracts/oft/libs/OFTComposeMsgCodec.sol

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [Pad Left](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-utils.html#padleft) documentation, you'd see that you don't need to do any conversion. You simply should do a `web3.utils.padLeft(address, 64)`. Given that you want bytes32, that is a total of 64 hex digits, you just need to fill the difference in 0s for in order to have 64 digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ethers.js

```
'0x'.concat(contract.address.slice(2).padStart(64, '0'))
```